# CSS Divs not aligned correctly

Tags: css, html

I feel like this is such an idiotic question, and the little things in css always get me. Anyway, I have a design, and I'm trying to do 2 columns. One (which is a sidebar of 300px) which is at the right, and the other column should fill the remaining space.

[image]
As you can see the sidebar is put under the div on the left.

HTML:

```
<div class="wfix"><div class="col-fix">
    <div class="col-lg">
    <!-- 
       <div id="block">
           <bh>Homepage</bh>
        <detail id="test">Loading...</detail>
       </div> 
     -->
    </div>

    <div class="col-side">

    </div>
</div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.wfix{ margin-left: 5em; margin-right: 5em; }
.col-fix {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.col-lg, .col-side {
    color: #999;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.col-lg {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 300px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: blue;
    min-height: 500px;
}
.col-side {
    width: 300px;
    float: right;
    padding-top: 0px;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: red;
    min-height: 500px;
}
```

thanks for any help, Jake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating elements should appear first in the html:

```
<div class="wfix">
   <div class="col-fix">
      <div class="col-side"></div>
      <div class="col-lg"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8Qsqs/)

Comment: wow fixed! I knew it was something minor. Why should floating elements appear first? Seems weird.

Comment: @Jakes625 Because floating elements can't alter previous elements, only following ones. And in your case you want `#col-side` to push `#col-lg`, so `#col-side` should appear first.